# Implementing a database Schema using MySQL and then populating with flights data from a CSV- how to set a bool tag to true/ false manually?

Tags: sql, mysql

Assignment for my DBMS class. We are to design and implement a relational database. We define a schema use MySQL statements. We are using this dataset that has to do with flights and collisions with wildlife. We create the schema, and then populate the database with data from the CSV.

So we have a flights table. One column in the flights table is "isHeavy" which is a boolean that is "true" if the aircraft is heavy, and "false" otherwise, using data from the csv.. The "heavy_flag" column in the actual CSV uses "yes" and "no" values.

I don't know if I'm overthinking this, but how do I set the flag to be " true" if the csv says " yes" for heavy and "false" otherwise, in the table definition? This is what I have so far.

( This is then passed into to dbExecute() to actually run the statement. I will likely have to takedown this post later, as this assignment is a copyrighted at my university.

```
f <- past0(
  " CREATE TABLE flights(",
    "fid INT NOT NULL",
    "date DATE NOT NULL",
    "originAirport INT NOT NULL",
    "airlineName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL",
    "aircraftType VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL",
    "isHeavy BOOL NOT NULL,",
    "PRIMARY KEY (fid)",
    "FOREIGN KEY (originAirport) REFERENCES airports(aid)",
    
  ")"
  
)
```

Would it be something like this?

```
f <- past0(
  " CREATE TABLE flights(",
    "fid INT NOT NULL",
    "date DATE NOT NULL",
    "originAirport INT NOT NULL",
    "airlineName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL",
    "aircraftType VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL",
    "isHeavy BOOL TRUE if "is_heavy" = "yes" else FALSE,",
    "PRIMARY KEY (fid)",
    "FOREIGN KEY (originAirport) REFERENCES airports(aid)",
    
  ")"
  
)
```

Please help, I don't know why this is confusing me so much.

Comment: Nope, you would handle this during the import.

Comment: Thanks. That's what chat said as well but it just didn't seem accurate to me?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your flights table created (... "So we have a flights table. ...") with a BOOLEAN last column...
If you have your csv data imported into database table or you can have it as a dataset like:

```sql
/*
FID A_DATE      ORIGINAL_AIRPORT    AIRLINE_NAME    AIRCRAFT_TYPE   IS_HEAVY
--- ----------  ------------------  --------------  --------------  ---------
1   2024-02-25  101                 Ryanair         A-320           no
2   2024-02-25  102                 AirFrance       A-380           yes
3   2024-02-25  103                 Vueling         A-319           no    */
```

... you could use it to insert data into flights table using case expression converting 'yes' to 1 (or TRUE with no quotes) and 'no' to 0 (or FALSE with no quotes)

```sql
INSERT INTO flights
  ( Select FID, A_DATE, ORIGINAL_AIRPORT, AIRLINE_NAME, AIRCRAFT_TYPE,
           Case When IS_HEAVY = 'yes' Then 1  -- or TRUE instead of 1
           Else 0                             -- or FALSE instead of 0
           End as IS_HEAVY
    From csv_flights
  );
```

```sql
--   test it
Select * From flights;
/*    R e s u l t :
FID A_DATE      ORIGINAL_AIRPORT    AIRLINE_NAME    AIRCRAFT_TYPE   IS_HEAVY
--- ----------  ------------------  --------------  --------------  ---------
1   2024-02-25  101                 Ryanair         A-320           0
2   2024-02-25  102                 AirFrance       A-380           1
3   2024-02-25  103                 Vueling         A-319           0       */
```

If you are doing it while reading csv out of db and passing commands to a database - do the same - convert 'yes' to 1 (TRUE) and 'no' to 0 (FALSE) while creating a command to be executed in db.